# WinForms Use Windows Aero Theme when Windows Theme is set to Classic

Tags: c#

I was wondering if someone found a way to keep a Windows form Application designed with the Windows 7 Aero theme to keep the Aero theme when the theme on the computer is switched to Classic. When a user switches there theme to classic all of the controls look like pre windows xp style. Thanks for any help anyone can provide

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to custom-draw *everything* to emulate the theme you want to display.  Anything drawn by the standard drawing APIs will use the theme the user has selected.  It's a lot of effort to go to just to poke your users in the eye though.

Comment: I ran into same issue, and @Corey has it, when people turn DWM off or pick a classic theme it makes our app look like total crap.  Nothing to do about it but tell them to pick the right theme (assuming you don't want to custom draw :))

Comment: And don't even think of trying to set the theme for them.

Answer (score 0):

Corey's comment is spot-on, however programs still shouldn't look "bad" when in classic mode (Office 2003 looks better, actually), so I suggest making some visual tweaks to your program :)

Can you post a screenshot so we can provide some guidance?

Note that in future this will be a non-issue because under Windows 8 themes cannot be disabled.